# Jquery Supersized! plugin with dynamic images path

Tags: php, image, path, supersized

I have a problem with the supersized jquery plugin, i was looking around about similar questions in this forum, i found an answer and try to adapt it to my issue, but is doesn't work, because i am a kind of new in php, so maybe someone could help me to adjust my function.

I am working on a dynamic website, I don't know neither the number, nor the title of the images.

I have several functions to call them that works but i don't manage to regroup them into a function that i could insert into the supersized! plugin

Here are my different elements :
this would always be the same configuration :

First single image :

```
    <img src='/cspdocs/exhibition/images/<?php echo $expo['pic'];?>'/>
```

for the others i need to use a loop foreach

second group of images :

```
    <?php foreach (getExpoViews($id_expo) AS $id_view) { ?>
    <img src='/cspdocs/exhibition/images/<?php echo getExpoViewImage($id_view)?>' title : '<?php echo $expo['name']'?> />   
    <?php }; ?>
```

third goup of images :

```
    <?php foreach (getExpoArtworks($id_expo) AS $id_artwork) {?>
    <img src="/cspdocs/artwork/images/<?php echo getArtworkThumbnail($id_artwork); ?>" title="<?php echo getArtistFullName(getArtworkArtist($id_artwork));?>" />
    <?php }; ?>
```

I don't know how to regroup them,
I start something like that for the second group of images
but it doesn't work :

```
    <?php 
    function getAllExpoView($path) {
    if (getExpoViews($id_expo)!='') {
      foreach (getExpoViews($id_expo) AS $id_view) { 
      $images= "{image : '/cspdocs/exhibition/images/'".getExpoViewImage($id_view)."', title : '".$expo['name']."', thumb :'/cspdocs/exhibition/images/'".getExpoViewImage($id_view)."',url :  ''},";   
      }; 
     return $images ;
 }; 
    }; 
   ?>
```

the goal is to replace the path here, the first image is ok, it is for my second and third groups :

```
    jQuery(function($){

            $.supersized({
                            slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                    {image : '/cspdocs/exhibition/images/<?php echo $expo['pic'];?>', title : '<?php echo $expo['name']; ?>', thumb : '/cspdocs/exhibition/images/<?php echo $expo['pic'];?>', url : '<?php echo $link;?>'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-2.jpg', url : '<?php echo $link;?>'}
                                            ]
        });
   });
```

here the link to the pre-prod website:

http://jeromesohier.curator-studio.com